# Minimise CPU and memory consumption on Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtual-machine, resource-management

I need to run a Windows-10 VM inside OSX (using VirtualBox) as I am using a Tobii EyeX eyetracker, which only has drivers for Windows.

I am working from a MacBook Air (8GB RAM), and running a VM is going to be a stretch.

Seeing as this is going to be the only thing running in my VM, I would like to eliminate any unnecessary memory consumption and CPU activity.

How can I reduce resource consumption to an absolute minimum?

EDIT: https://www.ntlite.com/download/

Comment: use the Windows 10 LTSB version which comes without all those store apps. this reduces CPU and memory usage a lot.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I can't find any information saying that LTSB version would "come without all those store apps", or that having less apps would use less memory or CPU, since you're not running them anyway.

Comment: http://winaero.com/blog/there-is-a-windows-10-edition-without-universal-apps-pre-installed/ those apps and background services which are needed by the store apps can comsime a lot of RAM. I tested the LTSB and got 300MB less RAM usage